# Keep header from file1 and add column from file2 to file1

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I need to copy a specific column from file2 to my file1, while keeping the header from file1.

File1:

```
##header
##header
##header
A1 B1 C1
A2 B2 C2
```

File2:

```
D1 E1 F1
D2 E2 F2
```

newfile:

```
##header
##header
##header
A1 B1 C1 E1
A2 B2 C2 E2
```

my attempts:

```
awk -F '\t' 'NR==3; NR>3 {getline f1 <"file1" ;print f1,$2}' OFS='\t' file2> newfile
```

or

```
awk 'NR==3; NR>3 {print $2}' < file2 | paste file1 -> newfile
```

Can someone give me a hand with this please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming both File1 and File2 are originally tab delimited, you could do something like this:

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'NR>3 {x = $0; $0 = (getline < "File2") > 0 ? x FS $2 : x} 1' File1
##header
##header
##header
A1      B1      C1      E1
A2      B2      C2      E2
```

Checking the return value of `getline` is good practice - in this case, it would prevent appending the "wrong" `$2` in the case that `File2` runs out of data before the end of `File1`.

Comment: How can I check the value of `getline`? 
After checking the newfile, it seems to be the result I was looking for. Thank you!!

Comment: @user1197728 please see updated answer

Comment: ok, I understand it. Both files should have the same number of lines (excluding header), but just to be sure I'll check it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `coreutils`, e.g.:

```
{
  # Extract the header from file1
  head -n3 file1
  
  # Combine file1 without the header with column 2 of file2
  paste <(tail -n+4 file1) <(cut -f2 file2)
} > newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash

```bsh
exec 7<"File2"
i=0
while read -r line
do
    ((i++))
    if (($i > 3))
    then
        read -r f1 f2 f3 <&7
        echo "$line $f2"
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done <"File1"
exec 7<&-
```